# Is it possible to disable custom logging in application insights for already deployed code?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

We are storing some user info in production that we don't have to keep and thus need to disable custom logging in application insights immediately. I can't change the code in between production rollouts.

Is there any setting or configuration available in application insights?

Comment: You have to do it on the app side before sending it to AppInsights. What language is your app in? What platform are you running it on? etc pp

Comment: It's an angular project.

Comment: ... hosted where? App Service? AKS?

Comment: @silent, there is now a way to drop data after it already made to Application Insights ingestion service. Please refer to the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

One solution which will not require code redeployment:

1. If using Classic Application Insights resource -> migrate to Workspace-based (no code changes required)
2. Use [Workspace transformation DCR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/data-collection-transformations#workspace-transformation-dcr)

Using them you can either completely drop data or can erase some fields.

Note, though dropped data doesn't appear in Application Insights, since it was ingested, it still will be partially charged (please refer to documentation).

Note, Workspace schema for Application Insights tables is slightly different. Transformation DCR needs to be written in Workspace schema. For instance, "requests" table name is called "AppRequests" in Workspace. You can explore individual fields by opening this table in Workspace directly.